# iOS Push Notification not being sent from linux server

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I currently have an application that sends push notifications to APNS, if I run this application locally on my computer (where i do my development) it sends the push notification without any error, however once i put the application on my linux server the exact same code with same device tokens fails to send and receives a "BadDeviceToken" error from APNS.

What would cause me to get this error on my server but not on my local computer? The .p12 certificate I have on my server is taken from my development APNS cert in my keychain on my local computer.

Any suggestions would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I didn't realise that using Test flight actually requires production apps certificates.
Changed to using them and it all worked, apple should really have a different error message for that case so people don't spend all that time debugging the device token...